# Driver error while connecting to interbase with pentaho Spoon

Tags: jdbc, pentaho, kettle, interbase

I am getting below error while trying to connect Interbase with pentaho Spoon.

> failed. Verify all connection parameters and confirm that the appropriate driver is installed.
> [interclient] Unlicensed component: This version of InterClient refuses communication with InterBase version WI-V7.5.1.80/tcp

The driver used is Interclient JDBC driver downloaded from https://dbschema.com/jdbc-driver/interbase.html

Interbase version is 7.5, and kettle version is PDI 9.4. I tried with jaybird driver, but that also doesn't work.
Any suggestions please.

Comment: Jaybird will definitely not work, because it is for Firebird only, not for InterBase. In any case the error suggests that you either have a version mismatch between InterClient and InterServer, or you're missing the appropriate license key.